# acr122 tag reader application on OS X

Tags: post, osx-lion, nfc

I need to make an application that sends a POST with data to a web service when a user taps a tag to the ACR122U nfc reader. The application needs to continue running on it's own after starting it and send POST's each time a tag is tapped. Control over the POST url in the application is required for conditional logic based on the tag data. This is for a brief POC installation with no more than 500 tag swipes within a 4 hour window. There will be a reader and a screen displaying a web page with an accumulating list as the user taps a few tags.

Since I have a MacBook Pro (OS X 10.7), I have tried several approaches with that platform. Unfortunately, without success. I would prefer an OS X solution, but am open to suggestions.

Given the following, what do I need to do? Is there a better/easier way?

1. tagstand_writer:

   - The ACR122U came with software called 'tagstand_writer_macosx_0_6_5_beta'. tagstand_writer does not seem to encompass the functionality I want. It seems only to enable simple read/write without continuous polling. Can it be used by a wrapper application that does the polling, or can it be used in a way I am not aware of to achieve the desired functionality? Anyway, I tried to write a url to my tag, per the instructions, but was unable to. I forget what the problem was, but it didn't seem worth pursuing. I was, however, able to read the tag per the instructions.
2. [libnfc](http://www.libnfc.org/)

   - Searching for clues, I stumbled upon libnfc. So, I took a deep breadth and braved the install process. It didn't go very well. The documentation is 'ok'  (not stumble-proof), and the process was challenging. I hit a few pot holes in the configure/make process and it took a while. Eventually, I was able to get one of the examples running. But, I wasn't sure what to do next. It seems pretty low level. There is an example provided called 'nfc-poll' but, it exits after a tag is read and I'm not sure if I can make that do what I want. I think this is the most promising of my 3 attempts, but am not sure what to do next.
3. [tageventor](http://code.google.com/p/tageventor/)

   - Looking for a higher-level starting point, I found tageventor. It seemed promising in that tagEventor, once started, is supposed to run and poll and call a script when a tag is read. The script, supposedly can be anything. So, I tried, but was unable to get it working. I found a [more current version](https://github.com/bettse/tagEventor) on github and tried that as well to no avail. I could get tagEventor to run, but when I touched a tag to the reader there was an error: "ERROR: readerCheck:: RPC transport error". I have no idea what that is, and neither does the internet apparently. Also, while trying to debug tageventor, I did notice that my console was outputting an error: "token in reader ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 00 00 cannot be used (error 229)" regardless of whether tageventor was running or not.

What's the simple/quick solution?

Comment: Have you find solution for this problem? I have similar one so I would really appreciate if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I did not find an OS X solution in time and used a Windows box, which was quite easy. The SDK is made for Windows: http://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/12/acr122u-nfc-contactless-smart-card-reader-software-developmnt-kit/

Comment: Still haven't found anything for OSX?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use something like :
echo 1 | pcsctest >out.txt
cat out.txt | grep "Current Reader ATR Value     " | tr -d " " | tr ":" " " | awk '{print $2}'
in your app to get the ART , you can create a bash script and put it in the daemon mode if you like

Comment: I wasn't aware of ``pcsctest``, nice find!  I'm unable get anything to register from my ACR122T, but still...